# Prove or disprove: $\bigcup_{n\ge1}\left[0,\frac n{n+1}\right]=[0,1)$ and $\bigcap_{n\ge1}\left[0,\frac n{n+1}\right]=\{0\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For integers $ n \ge 1 $, let $ A _ n = \left \{ x \in \mathbb R \Biggm | 0 \le x \le \frac n { n + 1 } \right \} = \left [ 0 , \frac n { n + 1 } \right ] $. Prove or disprove the statements below:
>
> 1. $ \bigcup _ { n \ge 1 } A _ n = [ 0 , 1 ) $
> 2. $ \bigcap _ { n \ge 1 } A _ n = \{ 0 \} $

My textbook for my class does not contain any notes on how to solve things like this. Any help solving these or links to sites that can show me how to solve things like this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first step would be to figure out whether the statements are true or not (even if you don't yet have a proof). Try simplifying the first few intervals, i.e. for $n = 1$, $n = 2$, $n = 3$, and maybe $n = 4$. Try plotting them on a number line. What do you notice? What happens if you take their union? What happens if you take their intersection? Once you figure out which statements are true and which are false, then you can then better figure out a plan of attack. For example, are we certain that $0$ is the *only* point in common between the intervals? Can you name another?

Comment: When you say the textbook "does not contain any notes on how to solve things like this," do you mean it has no worked examples of similarly nested unions and intersections of intervals?  Surely at some point the underlying *notation* has to be defined, and a starting point is to identify the values $x$ that belong to any one of the intervals (union) or to all of the intervals (intersection).

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you have to prove that two sets are equal (each of them has the exact same elements), the most reliable method is called "double inclusion". Basically, to show that $A$ and $B$ are equal, you have to show that:
(a) every element of $A$ is an element of $B$ (mathematically we write this as $A\subseteq B$, and say $A$ is a subset of $B$), and
(b) every element of $B$ is an element of $A$ (again that would be $B\subseteq A$, $B$ is a subset of $A$).

This of course would imply that the only elements of $A$ are elements of $B$, and vice versa, thus meaning $A=B$. So we will do that here:

**1.** Let's first show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n\subseteq [0,1)$. Let $x\in\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$, we have to prove that $x$ is in $[0,1)$. But this is clear, since by definition of union we have that an element of the union belongs to at least one of the sets we are taking the union of. In other words, there exists a certain $A_n$, for a certain $n\geq 1$ such that $x\in A_n$. And, by definition of $A_n$, since $A_n=[0,\frac{n}{n+1}]$, we have $0\leq x\leq \frac{n}{n+1}$. Now, because $n<n+1$, their quotient $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is less than $1$: so, in the above reasoning for $x$, we can conclude $0\leq x\leq\frac{n}{n+1}<1$. Therefore $x\in[0,1)$, like we wanted to show.

For the counterpart, let's see that $[0,1)\subseteq\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$. Let $x\in[0,1)$, meaning that $0\leq x<1$. We have to show that $x$ is in the union $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n$, and that means exactly that we need to prove $x$ is in $A_n$, for some $n$. However, since $$
\frac{n}{n+1}\longrightarrow 1 $$
as $n$ goes to $\infty$, and $x$ is strictly less than $1$, there exists a certain $N\geq 1$, possibly very large, such that $x\in\left[0,\frac{N}{N+1}\right]$ (remember $x$ is fixed). But that means that $x$ is in $A_N$, and by our previous reasoning this implies that $x\in\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$ (because $x\in A_n$ for some $n$).

By double inclusion, because every element of $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$ is an element of $[0,1)$, and every element of $[0,1)$ is part of $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$, we conclude that both sets are equal: that is, $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n=[0,1)$

**2** For the second one you can do the same thing, noting that an element $x$ is in the intersection $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} A_n$ if and only if, by definition of intersection, $x\in A_n$ for every $n$. Also there must be some copying error because $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} \neq \{0\}$, I assume $n$ starts at $0$. To do this, we reason the exact same way. Let's first show $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} A_n \subseteq \{0\}$. So, let $x\in\bigcap_{n\geq 0} A_n$; we have to show that $x\in\{0\}$. This means, that for every $n\geq 0$, we have
$$
x\in A_n=\left[0,\frac{n}{n+1}\right] \Rightarrow 0\leq x \leq \frac{n}{n+1};
$$
in particular $x\in A_0$, so $x\in\left[0,0\right]=\{0\}$.

For the reverse, to show $\{0\}\subseteq\bigcap_{n\geq 0} A_n$, let $x\in\{0\}$ (this means $x=0$, by the way). Then, to see $x$ is in the intersection we have to show $x\in A_n$ for every $n\geq 0$. But this is true, since for all $n$ we have
$$
x=0\in\left[0,\frac{n}{n+1}\right],
$$
meaning that $x\in\bigcap_{n\geq 0} A_n\subseteq\{0\}$.

By double inclusion, we see $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} A_n=\{0\}$.

Comment: The intervals are nested and increasing, so their intersection is just the first of them.  There's no reason to assume a typo here.

Comment: @RobertShore yes, I know that, but OP clearly doesn't. Also, A_1 is [0,1/2], not {0}

Answer (score 1):

One idea to prove this problem is to see that
$$A_n \subset A_{n+1},$$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, for $n \rightarrow \infty$, we have $$\dfrac{n}{n+1} \rightarrow 1.$$
Hence, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n = [0,1)$.
Furthermore, by the same inclusion $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$, it is easy to see that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n \geq 1} A_n = A_1$.